# trying to add different types inside if statement

Tags: c#, .net, linq, .net-core, refactoring

I have a below method where I am loop through the list of id's and getting the data from db based on id and then creating the material and then adding to material list

```
public Construction AddToOsm(Model model, APIDbContext dbContext)
{   
    var construction = new Construction(model);
    var surfaceType = dbContext.IntendedSurfaceTypes.SingleOrDefault(s => s.Id == this.SurfaceTypeId);
    construction.setName(surfaceType?.Name);
    using var materials = new MaterialVector();

    var fenestrationMaterialById = new Dictionary<Guid, FenestrationMaterial>();
    var opaqueMaterialById = new Dictionary<Guid, StandardOpaqueMaterial>();
    foreach (var materialId in this.LayerIds.Where(i => i != default))
    {
        var opaqueMaterial = dbContext.OpaqueMaterials.SingleOrDefault(o => o.Id == materialId);
        if (opaqueMaterial != default)
        {
            materials.Add(opaqueMaterialById.GetOrCreate(opaqueMaterial.Id, () => opaqueMaterial.AddToOsm(model)));
        }
        else
        {
            var glazingMaterial = dbContext.GlazingMaterials.SingleOrDefault(o => o.Id == materialId);
            if (glazingMaterial != default)
            {
                materials.Add(fenestrationMaterialById.GetOrCreate(glazingMaterial.Id, () => glazingMaterial.AddToOsm(model)));
            }
            else
            {
                var glazingSimpleMaterial = dbContext.SimpleGlazingMaterials.SingleOrDefault(s => s.Id == materialId);
                if(glazingSimpleMaterial != default)
                {
                    materials.Add(fenestrationMaterialById.GetOrCreate(glazingSimpleMaterial.Id, () => glazingSimpleMaterial.AddToOsm(model)));
                }
                else
                {
                    var gasGlazingMaterials = dbContext.GasGlazingMaterials.SingleOrDefault(a => a.Id == materialId);
                    if(gasGlazingMaterials != default)
                    {
                        materials.Add(fenestrationMaterialById.GetOrCreate(gasGlazingMaterials.Id, () => gasGlazingMaterials.AddToOsm(model)));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    construction.setLayers(materials);
    return construction;
}
```

I am looking a way to avoid this much of if-else statements mainly refactoring this but could not find a way to do. Could any one please suggest any idea on how to achieve the same.

Thanks in advance.

update: sample entity structure

```
public class GasGlazingMaterial : ISourceOfData, IIdentity<Guid>
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("SourceOfData")]
    public Guid? SourceOfDataId { get; set; }
    public virtual CodeStandardGuideline SourceOfData { get; set; }
    ......
    .....
 }
```

Comment: Usually, I solve repetitive `if` functions by using a loop. What if you made a list of objects and iterated through them? Then for each one check `if object = default: exit. else: continue`.

Comment: yeah the problem is if `object = default` then I need to check for other object if first one is not available

Comment: This looks to be testing for the material 'type' which makes me think that the data structure is actually causing the issue. I wonder if going back and looking at the database structure would be a good idea here.

It also is concerning that this code is testing the same 'ID' across multiple tables which I think is another red flag.

Comment: the actual structure is like this `public class SurfaceConstruction : IIdentity<Guid>
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public Guid SurfaceTypeId { get; set; }
        public IntendedSurfaceType SurfaceType { get; set; }
        public List<Guid> LayerIds { get; set; }
        public Construction AddToOsm(Model model, APIDbContext dbContext)
        { .....`

Comment: looping through the `LayerIds` and find corresponding material then add to materials and all material entities(`OpaqueMaterials...`) are deriving from `IIdentity<Guid>`

Comment: @blockingHD i updated sample entity structure and all materials are having those fields common, could you please suggest any other way to overcome these if -else statements

Comment: I think I finally have my head round this. All of these types if implemented in C#, ignoring the DB, would be implemented using polymorphism. The issue you have is that this isn't supported by SQL so from what I can see these are your options: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1172909/storing-polymorphic-objects-in-sql-database

Other than this I can't see a way to reduce the IF/ELSE blocks without querying the db up front or using continue. This is just inherently messy due to how the data needs to be queried.

Comment: if i use continue still i need to check for default right and if i implemented polymorphism the common things are only two or three fields and i am already using interface for that

Comment: if i use polymorphism could you please through a pseudo code how to rephrase above scenarios

Comment: @CyanCoding, could you please suggest how your suggestion will apply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple fix would be to "continue" after each materials.add.  This would mean you dont need to embed the rest in an else