# Dynamic Enums in C#

Tags: c#, .net

Say I have this enum:

```
public enum DynamicItem
{
FirstItem=1,
SecondItem=2
}
```

Is there any way to make that enum dynamic so that it's members can come from a database query, i.e. if I add 3/ThirdItem to the database table that new item is available in the Enum and this would work:

```
public class Example
{
public DynamicItem item = DynamicItem.ThirdItem
}
```

Comment: If you want it dynamic it should no longer be an enum. Enums help you in writing understandable code because you can code against the named values. So its a compile time thing. If you only know that at runtime then it does not seem helpful at all at. Said that you can cast any value of the backing type into an enum value you simply can do `(DynamicItem)0`. YOu just don't have a name for the value then.

Comment: Maybe you should have a T4 template load the enums off the database. Or use somthing like EF Power Tools.

Comment: If you want to map numbers to strings, perhaps a Dictionary would work well.

Answer (score 4):

I know exactly why you want to do this, so often one is mapping status flags or the like between database and code, but no, there's no way to do this.

It doesn't really make sense to do it either - typically we code against the enum values - what would you code against here?  And if you could, if they were to disappear at runtime because they were deleted from the database, you'd get runtime failures which would go against the static typing of C#.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases it may be useful to use a type to wrap an integer, something like

```
public readonly record struct DynamicItem(int Id)
{
    public static DynamicItem FirstItem { get; } = new(1);
    public static DynamicItem SecondItem { get; } = new(2);
    ....
}
```

This can allow you to refer to specific values in code using a friendly name, while using some default behavior for unknown values.

You will need to consider backward and forward compatibility. You can no longer assume the listed values are the only ones that exists, and you really need to make sure a specific value is not used to represent different things in different versions.

Ofc, your code cannot handle items it does not know about. So if values are added in the future they all get the same default behavior. Unless you add additional information to the database that describes what behavior they should have. I.e. your "enum" is really just a class, [possibly a polymorphic class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1172909/storing-polymorphic-objects-in-sql-database).